# Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the load path: Kitchen cannot find kitchen-vagrant's plugin

Tags: ruby, test-kitchen, chefdk

I've installed the latest ChefDK and running through one of the kitchen tutorials on the Chef site. When I run `kitchen list`, this is the error message I see:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ClientError
>>>>>> Message: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the load path. Please ensure that your driver is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

I've seen other issues here that indicate this may be related to multiple or an incompatible versions of kitchen-vagrant gem installed. When I run chef gem list kitchen-vagrant, I see the following:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
kitchen-vagrant (0.20.0)
```

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the gem as per guidance on other threads (i.e. installing version 0.16.0). However this has not solved the problem.

Also running chef -v gives me the following:

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.18.26
chef-client version: 12.14.89
delivery version: master (d86679335580be3de22996ef294b20d525889d8d)
berks version: ERROR
kitchen version: ERROR
```

I don't know why berks and kitchen would say error like this. I'm not a ruby dev so I'm unsure why I'm getting this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Also here is the result from kitchen diagnose --all if it helps:

```
---
timestamp: 2016-09-24 14:18:39 UTC
kitchen_version: 1.13.1
plugins:
  error:
    exception: "#<Kitchen::ClientError: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the
      load path. Please ensure that your driver is installed as a gem or included
      in your Gemfile if using Bundler.>"
    message: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the load path. Please ensure
      that your driver is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using
      Bundler.
    backtrace:
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:50:in
      `rescue in for_plugin'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:40:in
      `for_plugin'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in
      `new_driver'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:248:in
      `new_instance'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:144:in
      `block in build_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in
      `map'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in
      `with_index'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in
      `build_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:119:in
      `instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:115:in
      `filtered_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:145:in
      `parse_subcommand'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:56:in
      `load_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:35:in
      `block in call'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:80:in
      `record_failure'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:35:in
      `call'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:56:in
      `perform'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:142:in
      `diagnose'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
      `run'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in
      `invoke_command'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:334:in
      `invoke_task'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in
      `block in <top (required)>'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:174:in
      `with_friendly_errors'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in
      `<top (required)>'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `load'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `<main>'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'"
loader:
  process_erb: true
  process_local: true
  process_global: true
  global_config: 
  project_config:
    filename: "/Workspace/clique-infrastructure-repo/cookbooks/motd/.kitchen.yml"
    raw_data:
      driver:
        name: vagrant
      provisioner:
        name: chef_solo
      platforms:
      - name: ubuntu-14.04
      - name: centos-7.2
      suites:
      - name: default
        run_list:
        - recipe[motd::default]
        attributes: 
  local_config: 
  combined_config:
    filename: 
    raw_data:
      driver:
        name: vagrant
      provisioner:
        name: chef_solo
      platforms:
      - name: ubuntu-14.04
      - name: centos-7.2
      suites:
      - name: default
        run_list:
        - recipe[motd::default]
        attributes: 
instances:
  error:
    exception: "#<Kitchen::ClientError: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the
      load path. Please ensure that your driver is installed as a gem or included
      in your Gemfile if using Bundler.>"
    message: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the load path. Please ensure
      that your driver is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using
      Bundler.
    backtrace:
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:50:in
      `rescue in for_plugin'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:40:in
      `for_plugin'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in
      `new_driver'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:248:in
      `new_instance'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:144:in
      `block in build_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in
      `map'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in
      `with_index'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in
      `build_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:119:in
      `instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:115:in
      `filtered_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:145:in
      `parse_subcommand'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:56:in
      `load_instances'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:35:in
      `block in call'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:80:in
      `record_failure'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/diagnose.rb:35:in
      `call'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:56:in
      `perform'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:142:in
      `diagnose'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
      `run'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in
      `invoke_command'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:334:in
      `invoke_task'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in
      `block in <top (required)>'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:174:in
      `with_friendly_errors'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in
      `<top (required)>'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `load'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `<main>'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'"
    - "/Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'"
```

This is the result of `chef gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin13]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/Jaz/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/Jaz/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/chefdk/embedded/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/Jaz/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--user --no-document"
     - "update" => "--user --no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
     - /Users/Jaz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/gradle-2.8/bin
     - /usr/local/mysql/bin
     - /Users/Jaz/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
     - /Users/Jaz/Library/Android/sdk/tools
     - /Users/Jaz/.rvm/bin
```

This is the result of my .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log file:

```
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586307 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Exception-------
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586384 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: Class: Kitchen::ClientError
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586402 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: Message: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the load path. Please ensure that your driver is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586414 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----------------------
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586425 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Backtrace-------
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586435 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:50:in `rescue in for_plugin'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586446 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:40:in `for_plugin'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586456 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in `new_driver'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586467 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:248:in `new_instance'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586477 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:144:in `block in build_instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586487 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `map'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586497 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `with_index'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586507 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `build_instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586517 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:119:in `instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586528 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:115:in `filtered_instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586538 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:145:in `parse_subcommand'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586548 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/list.rb:32:in `call'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586558 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:56:in `perform'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586569 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:120:in `list'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586579 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586589 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586599 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:334:in `invoke_task'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586621 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586632 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586642 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586653 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:174:in `with_friendly_errors'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586663 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586673 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `load'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586683 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `<main>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586698 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586709 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586719 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----End Backtrace-----
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586729 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ---Nested Exception---
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586739 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: Class: LoadError
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586749 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: Message: cannot load such file -- kitchen/driver/vagrant
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586759 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----------------------
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586768 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Backtrace-------
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586778 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:50:in `rescue in for_plugin'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586788 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:40:in `for_plugin'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586798 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:235:in `new_driver'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586808 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:248:in `new_instance'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586818 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:144:in `block in build_instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586828 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `map'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586838 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `with_index'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586848 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:143:in `build_instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586858 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/config.rb:119:in `instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586868 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:115:in `filtered_instances'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586878 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command.rb:145:in `parse_subcommand'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586889 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/command/list.rb:32:in `call'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586898 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:56:in `perform'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586909 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:120:in `list'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586918 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586929 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586938 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:334:in `invoke_task'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586948 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586958 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586968 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586978 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:174:in `with_friendly_errors'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.586988 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/test-kitchen-1.13.1/bin/kitchen:13:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.587001 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `load'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.587012 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/kitchen:23:in `<main>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.587021 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.587031 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: /Users/Jaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
E, [2016-09-24T15:35:12.587041 #1273] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----End Backtrace-----
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same problem and tried to follow the suggestions found on [github](https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/15).  That didn't work.

Finally, this is what resolved the issue for me:

- Re-install ChefDK, downloading it from [Chef](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk) site
- `gem install kitchen-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is, that you dont use ruby from chef with its gems, but your ruby given by the platform you have installed.
You can find out which ruby version you are running by:

```
which ruby
```

which should return a path to

```
/opt/opscode
```

or something alike

if not
Try

```
chef exec kitchen list
```

with this you will use the chef own kitchen and thus its environments.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I had was ubuntu's ruby being different than the chefdk ruby.

I ended up following advice from here:

https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_ChefDK_on_Ubuntu

basically put this in your .bash_profile:

```
eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"
```

It will update your paths properly.

Just be careful, .bash_profile is only run on first login, and not on subsequent terminals being open. run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Otherwise you may want to reboot, or at least logout and login again.